# Message transmission on TCP/IP server with ctrl+c int handling, Python3

Tags: python, sockets

i'm just started to learn Python, and i can't implement a good solution.

I want to write a client/server which allows you to send messages (like: texted, entered, texted, entered) on server until you press Ctrl+C interruption, and this int should close the socket both on server and client.

My very basic and, i suppose, very common client/server example on Python, but as you know - this pair is for single shot, and program is closing.

client.py

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFERSIZE = 1024

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

msg = input('Enter your text: ')
sock.send(msg.encode())
data = sock.recv(BUFFERSIZE).decode()
sock.close()

print('Recieved data: ',data)
```

server.py

```
import socket
import sys

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
sock.listen(1)

conn, addr = sock.accept()
print('Connection address:\nIP:',addr[0])
print('Port:',addr[1])
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    msg = data.decode()
    print('Recieved data: ', msg)
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Control-C will end the script, and that should automatically close the socket.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the question is how to send stacks of messages on server, like in a chat, and client to be closed and handled nicely (without tracebacks etc.) after you've done with messaging by interruption (as an option - to let the server go on after client side closed up, but it's not necessary right now). My code can send **only one** message and close after all.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, it does. But tracebacks , etc. In my case `Enter your text: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blablabla\client.py", line 10, in <module>
EOFError`. Not cool, right?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `try...finally` to the bottom part like so:

```
try:
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not data: break
        msg = data.decode()
        print('Recieved data: ', msg)
        conn.send(data)
finally:
    conn.close()
```

Ctrl+C raises `KeyboardInterrupt` exception. When it does, the `finally` will be called, and safely close the socket.

The same can be done to the client in order to close it client-side:

```
try:
    msg = input('Enter your text: ')
    sock.send(msg.encode())
    data = sock.recv(BUFFERSIZE).decode()
finally:
    sock.close()
```

Comment: Well, the interruption handling is done, but, that's not what i really need. I need to send messages on server like: texted, pressed enter, texted, pressed enter. And interruption is needed to abort texting, closing the sockets and returning back to the cmd